# Disconnecting client with error: client socket write error: Broken pipe - passenger 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

When I start *Phusion [Passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger) Standalone web server* (version `5.0.2`), I see the following error in the log (even though everything works fine otherwise):

```
ServerKit/Server.h:892 ]: [Client 1-1] Disconnecting client with error: client socket write error: Broken pipe (errno=32)
```

Any idea what might be causing it?

Note: I start the server with `foreman start` and I stop it with `control-c`.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1422) is official discussion of this problem.

Comment: Thanks - Google had not yet seen it, as it was posted only 7 hours ago, and I did not think to check GitHub.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Passenger author here. Actually, the issue maxd linked to has got nothing to do with it.

The "Disconnecting client with error: client socket write error: Broken pipe" is a harmless informational message. It's quite normal, but I forgot to give it a lower logging level. I will do that in the next release. You can safely ignore this message. Nothing bad is going on.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to check SO. And thank you so much for passenger!